# SPF Configuration for Mandrill and MailChimp?

Tags: email, dns, mailchimp, spf, mandrill

I am planing to use both Mandrill and MailChimp for my website, and I`m trying to set up the crazy SPF DKIM for both of them. At same time still keep my own email flowing In and Out :)

My current plan is :

```
SPF TXT Record

yourdomain.com 
v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
1 hour

And a DKIM Record (for only Mandrill)

mandrill._domainkey.yourdomain.com
k=rsa; p=*****
1 hour
```

Can anyone see any missing characters? And is MailChimp Domain still Valid?
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should be able to omit the Mandrill info from your SPF record, because it's already included by virtue of including the MailChimp one (that MailChimp record includes Mandrill, too).  So you just need the `include:servers.mcsv.net` part.

Your SPF record might need some other info, too, though, depending on how you manage your regular mail, to specifically authorize your own servers to send the mail.  For example, if you use Google Apps for your domain, you probably want to include the Google SPF information, too.  That's going to be pretty dependent on your regular mail, so best to contact your email hosting provider for more details on how to handle it specific to them.